# Python Pandas, slice rows from group in .groupby().apply()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, slice

I have the following code setup that calls and groupBy and apply on a Python Pandas DataFrame.

The bizarre thing is I am unable to slice the grouped data by row (like `df.loc[2:5]`) without it completely screwing the output (as shown in the debug), how can you drop rows and get this to give the desired output?

Any help would be massively appreciated, I'm running this on a bigger example with more complicated functions, but have pinpointed the issues to the row slicing!

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : ['AAL', 'AAL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL'], 'two' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})

def net_func(df):
    df_res = daily_func(df, True)
    df_res_valid = daily_func(df, False)
    df_merge = pd.merge(df_res, df_res_valid)
    return df_merge

def daily_func(df, bool_param):

#     df.drop(df.head(1).index, inplace=True)
#     df = df[1:1]
#     df.iloc[1:1,:]
#     df.loc[1:1,:]


    if bool_param:
        df['daily'+str(bool_param)] = 1
    else:
        df['daily'+str(bool_param)] = 0    
    return df

print df.groupby('one').apply(net_func)
```

Current output:

```
         one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
one                                     
AAL  0   AAL    1          1           0
     1   AAL    2          1           0
AAPL 0  AAPL    1          1           0
     1  AAPL    2          1           0
```

Desired output:

```
         one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
one                                     
AAL  1   AAL    2          1           0
AAPL 1  AAPL    2          1           0
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to slice by row for each group for example `df.loc[3:5]` - This would be perfect!

I've tried the commented as follows:

output with `df.drop(df.head(1).index, inplace=True)`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [one, two, dailyTrue, dailyFalse]
Index: []
```

Update: also tried output with `df = df[1:1]`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [one, two, dailyTrue, dailyFalse]
Index: []
```

Update have also tried `df.iloc[1:1,:]`:

```
         one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
one                                     
AAL  0   AAL    1          1           0
     1   AAL    2          1           0
AAPL 0  AAPL    1          1           0
     1  AAPL    2          1           0
```

and `df.loc[1:1,:]`:

```
         one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
one                                     
AAL  0   AAL    1          1           0
     1   AAL    2          1           0
AAPL 0  AAPL    1          1           0
     1  AAPL    2          1           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the cross section slice, [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) after the `groupby().apply()`, specifying each key accordingly:

```
print df.groupby('one').apply(net_func).xs(0, level=1)
#       one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
#one                                   
#AAL    AAL    1          1           0
#AAPL  AAPL    1          1           0

print df.groupby('one').apply(net_func).xs(1, level=1)
#       one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
#one                                   
#AAL    AAL    2          1           0
#AAPL  AAPL    2          1           0
```

Alternatively, use [multiple indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-mi-slicers) with list of tuples:

```
print df.groupby('one').apply(net_func).ix[[('AAL', 1), ('AAPL', 1)]]
#         one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
#one                                     
#AAL  1   AAL    2          1           0
#AAPL 1  AAPL    2          1           0
```

Still more with slice (introduced in pandas 0.14):

```
print df.groupby('one').apply(net_func).loc[(slice('AAL','AAPL'),slice(1,1)),:]
#         one  two  dailyTrue  dailyFalse
#one                                     
#AAL  1   AAL    2          1           0
#AAPL 1  AAPL    2          1           0
```

Comment: I really appreciate this, and I will try straight away, but is there no way to do it inside the function?

The reason I ask is because in the actual code there are a lot more steps that happen after the relevant rows are dropped

Comment: Or, could I use this method you showed to slice `n` rows from each group at index `start:end`?

Comment: These above methods expect multi-index dfs which occur only after you apply your function. Maybe wrapping another function with this output as input?

Answer (score 4):

I felt the need for slicing inside `GroupBy` object and I have been doing so by applying this monkey patch:

```py
def __groupby_slice( _grp, start=0, stop=None, step=1):
    '''
    Applies a slice to a GroupBy object
    '''
    return _grp.apply( lambda _df : _df.iloc[start:stop:step]).reset_index(drop=True)

pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.slice = __groupby_slice
```

Use as:

```py
df.groupby('feature0').slice(-10, -3, 2)
```

Works with `pandas==0.25.3`

Comment: This is an (interesting ?) approach. Going to pop this concept into my pocket for later use. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use an iloc in groupby.apply:

```py
groupby.apply(lambda group: group.iloc[start:stop:step])
```