# Pandas groupby nlargest slice

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

There were kind of similar named questions, but they do not reflect the use case I am facing. I have a dataframe with groups and values. I want to select values sliced by their order (confusing maybe, example will explain better).

This is my data:

```py
group   value
a   20
a   16
a   14
a   13
a   12
b   19
b   17
b   16
b   14
b   13
b   12
b   12
b   11
```

I want to group by `group` and slice [a:b] with nlargest logic, in other words, if a = 2 and b = 7 the biggest 3rd, 4th, 5ht, 6th and 7th variables per each group. I could not find any question here on this use case, or could I find something in pandas-dev github.

If there are less than `b` elements in any of the groups, then `b = len(of that group)` should be applied. If there are two or more elements with the same value, they should all be selected if they are within the [a:b] slice.

My desired result looks like this:

```
group   value
a   14
a   13
a   12
b   16
b   14
b   13
b   12
b   12
```

Here, the group `a` has 5 elements which is less than `b` in the example and because of that, 3rd to the 5th biggest elements are returned. In group `b` 6th and 7th biggest values are the same, so they are both returned.

The closest question to mine is [this question about slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070288/python-pandas-slice-rows-from-group-in-groupby-apply#59896706) but it does not use nlargest logic. It just slices the groups.

If you could guide me on that, I would appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

gbg = df.groupby('group')

a=2
b=7
res = gbg['value'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.to_list(x)[a:b]).to_frame().explode('value').reset_index()
# .agg will "aggregate" the groups, here it will create the slices by group
# .to_frame will convert results from pd.Series to pd.DataFrame
# .explode() will write the list values in rows again
# .reset_index() will restore the column 'group'
```

The intermediate result after `.agg()`:

```py
group
a            [14, 13, 12]
b    [16, 14, 13, 12, 12]
Name: value, dtype: object
```

And the full result:

```py
  group value
0     a    14
1     a    13
2     a    12
3     b    16
4     b    14
5     b    13
6     b    12
7     b    12
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. After sorting the dataframe and using `slice` I could achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

By sorting the dataframe first and using the `slice` method which [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070288/python-pandas-slice-rows-from-group-in-groupby-apply#59896706) gives me the result I expected.

```py
df.sort_values(["group", "value"], ascending = False).groupby("group").slice(2, 7)
```

Output is

```
group   value
a   14
a   13
a   12
b   16
b   14
b   13
b   12
b   12
```